# command Testrpc is not working

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, testrpc

I installed Geth to work with Web3 and used `npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc`
but when i run testrpc the following error shows

`testrpc is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

Is there any additional package or something that I should use to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

From the [npm docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-testrpc) the testrpc package has been deprecated and moved to ganache-cli. My suggestion is to use that instead. But if you want to use test rpc then use the command

`geth --rpc` to set it going. Of course it would be better to check if you have the latest geth version as well in case it does not work but so far I have been using this in my testing and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

This package has been deprecated https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-testrpc

`ethereumjs-testrpc` has been renamed to `ganache-cli`, would be better to use new one.

If you face the issue again, make sure that Environment Variables contain path to
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm`